# Backbone doesn't respond

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I made a new backbone project and I wrote a simple console.log inside initialize function but it doesn't appear on my console. I can't understand the reason. In this website there is the project : http://www.felpone.netsons.org/car/www/

Comment: Your example is actually somewhat large. Try producing an SSCCE? (see http://sscce.org/) By reducing the example down, you may get a better idea of what part of your code is likely to be causing problems. Try to reduce your example down to just one route and/or just one view and hopefully it will be easier for you (and us!) to find any lingering issues.

Comment: I discovered that deviceready event is not fired!

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code in `main.js`:

```
// We launch the App
require(['backbone', 'utils'], function(Backbone, Utils) {
    require(['preloader', 'router'], function(PreLoader, AppRouter) {

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", run, false);

    function run() {
       console.log("asas");
       // ... and so on ...
```

Your `main.js` file defines a function, `run()` inside a few `require()` blocks, but it never actually calls it.  The `run()` function doesn't appear to be necessary; try just changing it to:

```
// We launch the App
require(['backbone', 'utils'], function(Backbone, Utils) {
    require(['preloader', 'router'], function(PreLoader, AppRouter) {

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", run, false);

   console.log("asas");
   // ... and so on ...
```

Your log statement should show up just fine.

Comment: Should not run function be called by addEventListener?

Comment: Only if `deviceready` is fired after all the RequireJS modules are loaded.  I suspect that event may actually be firing prior to the RequireJS callbacks are running.  Are you using Cordova with RequireJS?  If so, this might be a better structure to initialize things:  https://gist.github.com/shazron/5639820